# Sympy: replacing "-1" in expressions?

Tags: python, sympy

I am currently working with Sympy 1.0 and Python 2.7, and my aim is to replace every numerical parameter in an expression with a symbol.

For example:

```
2 * x + 3 * y - 10 * z -> a * x + b * y - c * z
```

So far I used `expression.atoms(Number)` to obtain the list of numerical parameters, to later replace them either using `.subs` or by writing everything to string and using `.replace`. However, I am facing an issue with expressions such as:

```
expression = sympy.simpify("x - z")
```

Where `-z` is actually `-1 * z` if I analyze the expression as a tree...but `-1` does not appear among the result of `expression.atoms(Number)`, so I cannot replace it.

Even converting the expression to a string to then use `.replace` does not really help, as `-1 * z` is always written out as `-z`.

There is probably some solution that I overlooked, but so far I am stuck. Can you help me? Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Are you sure?  `sympy.simplify('-x').atoms()` returns `{-1, x}` for me

Comment: You're right: I probably made a moronic error the first time I tried to use `subs`. I retried with `subs`. just now, and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: You're right, I will just do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it turns out I probably did a moronic error when I first tried to use `.subs`; as Patrick noted in the comments, `.subs` works perfectly in this case.